# mod_rewrite and php $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Tags: php, macos, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to create a redirect to a "proxy" script, every request will go through.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ dispatcher.php [QSA,L]
```

After rewrite I want to know the file path for the initially requested URL within dispatcher.php. Therefore I'm using the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` variable. Working so far on the linux machine with apache 2.2.16 but doesn't work on osx 10.8 with apache 2.2.22.

Somebody any idea why?

Comment: add ?params=$1 at the end of dispatcher.php then reference it with $_GET['params']. You may also want to check if file exists too otherwise dispatcher.php will re-write aswell

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is what you want to be using to get the originally requested URI un-modified.

Comment: I cannot add "file exists" check because files called exist. It seems, dispatcher redirects itself with an internal redirect. But, somehow it works on the debian linux system, without double redirect.

Comment: Just figured out, that mod_rewrite results are different, when configured via server setup or .htaccess.